# Is there any way to obtain different shuffled in randperm?

Tags: matlab, rows, shuffle

I have a matrix `[1 2 3 4]` and I want to shuffle it with `randperm` in few times but I want to obtain different matrices. For example

```
for i=1:4    
    m(i,:)=randperm(4); 
end
```

will give me 4 rows with 4 columns but I want every row to be different from every other one; e.g. like this:

```
m(1,:)=[1 3 4 2]
m(2,:)=[2 3 1 4]
m(3,:)=[2 1 4 3]
m(4,:)=[4 3 2 3]
```

Comment: How many elements are you permuting in your actual code? Are you using 4? 40?

Comment: I will permute for 9 elements. And what if I use 40, will it be any difference than 4?

Comment: It will make a difference because the approach I was going to suggest is to generate all permutations and then permute the indices of those permutations. Generating 9! permutations is feasible. Generating 40! permutations is not. But I see Suever has suggested the same approach. :)

Comment: Ok Thanks I got your point and I will use the easy one of @Suever suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check the existing rows to see if the current permutation already exists

```
m = zeros(4, 4);

counter = 1;

while counter < 4
    new = randperm(4); 
    if ~ismember(new, m, 'rows')
        m(counter, :) = new;
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end
```

Another (memory intensive) approach would be to generate *all* permutations and then randomly select N of them

```
allperms = perms(1:4);
N = 4;

m = allperms(randsample(size(allperms,1), N), :);
```

Comment: `randi(size(allperms,1), N, 1)` doesn't ensure the selected permutations will be different. Shouldn't it be `randsample(size(allperms,1), N)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo Doh you're right. Not enough coffee today :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Suever it satisfied my aim

Comment: @EmreKurt If it worked for you, please consider marking it as a solution using the checkmark to the left of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the MATLAB function `ismember` to check if the random permutation that you just created is already contained in your matrix.

So you can just try something like that:

```
for i=1:4
    temp = randperm(4);
    while ismember(m,temp,'rows')
      temp = randperm(4);
    end
    m(i,:) = temp;
end
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it.